# Updating DataGrid cell only works for root-object properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this entity

```
public class StockQuantity : EntityBase
{
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; internal set; }
}
```

Where `Part`

```
public class Part : EntityBase
{
    public string OEMNumber { get; set; }
    public string BellNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(9, 3)")]
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    public virtual StockQuantity StockQuantity { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartQuantity> PartQuantities { get; set; }

    public virtual CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Which I am binding to a `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding StockQuantities}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockQuantity}"
            x:Name="dataGridConsignments" 
            Margin="10,47,10,9.6"
            ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateQuantity}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Bell Number" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Part.BellNumber}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Part.Description}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="COO" Binding="{Binding Part.CountryCode.Code}"></DataGridTextColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Quantity" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"  Command="{Binding RowDoubleClick}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

In my `ViewModel` I have this command, which fires whenever a cell is edited:

```
public ICommand UpdateQuantity
{
    get
    {
        return updateQuantity
            ?? (updateQuantity = new ActionCommand(() =>
            {
                if (SelectedStockQuantity == null)
                    return;
                var stockQ = AllStockQuantities.FirstOrDefault(sq => SelectedStockQuantity.Id == sq.Id);
                if (stockQ == null)
                    return;
                StandardDatabase.Commands.UpdateStockQuantity(stockQ.Part.Id, SelectedStockQuantity.Quantity, SelectedStockQuantity.Part.CountryCode.Code);
            }));
    }

}
```

The problem is, when the command fires I can see the updated value for `Quantity` (which is a root-level property of `StockQuantity`), but when I try updating the `CountryCode` or `Description` then the original value is still stored in `SelectedStockQuantity`, and so it is not updated in the db.

Does anyone know how I can force `SelectedStockQuantity` to update child-object properties in this context?

Comment: Tried to set `Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for other bindings?

Comment: @Rekshino I tried that and it works in the back-end but when I update a row from say country code GB to ZA, then all GB code columns in the View change to ZA (but not in the db)

Comment: I can't follow you what do you mean with "all GB code columns"? Do you have right values in `SelectedStockQuantity`? If so, then the issue is not on WPF side, but on DB-side.